# What's the highest possible Sign intensity?

Tags: the-witcher-3

First of all I like to point out that I want to get the highest value without any conditions for it to trigger, so no "Focus" ability because it depends on adrenaline points. Also no temporary boosts like potions and decoctions.

Personally I believe it is achieved with following stuff:

- All legendary (NG+) mastercrafted griffin items. Unfortunately I
  don't know the stats for them yet. regular mastercrafted would be 70%
- Sword sockets full with Greater Veles Runestones = 15%
- Armor sockets full with all Greater (any) Glyphs.
  3 in chest, 2 in legs, 1 in boots, 1 in gloves. Is 7 times 10 %
  divided by 5 (because single element) = 14%
- "Griffin School Techniques" ability = 20%
- "Synergy" ability (see mutagens)
- The 5 blue abilities that grant 15% for each element respectively = 15%
- Fill the other abilities with other blue abilites
- 4 greater blue mutagens. Each normally gives 10% but because of "Synergy" 15% and also 15% for each blue ability. because of the 2 nonblue abilites we have = 60 + 60 + 60 + 30 = 210%

So now we have 344% sign intensity without legendary stats of griffin and from leveling up.

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/373bus/sign_intensity_explained/ you can get 28.1% from leveling up. Don't know if this still is acurate with the latest patch and NG+ but this would lead us to 372.1% plus some from the legendary items.

Is my setup optimal? and if someone has the stats from legendary mastercrafted griffin that would be great, I can't find it online.

Comment: fwiw there's a glitch involving synergy and the Dimeritium bomb that makes your intensity jump into the thousands, i'm not sure if its been fixed yet.

Comment: I don't know the total numbers, but unequip your sword if you want to do a pure signs build. Not having a sword in his hand doubles Geralt's Sign intensity, and Sword runes don't work unless the sword is in your hand

Comment: @Dallium i could be wrong but i believe they have patched that. At least, from my experience I used to see a notable change when unequipping and now not any more. But it could also mean that it is not noticeable because my sign intensity is that high already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting that help needed about the legendary Mastercrafted Griffin Armor to start, you can refer to this picture:

[image]

I double-checked myself, this is accurate as of recent to my knowledge, unless some patch/update alters or debuffs one of the armor(s) pieces or weapon in the set.

As for your setup, it's definitely ideal, however it's not the MAX sign intensity percentage. Other players have reached over 400% with the use of a optimal build and Foglet Decoction (only effective during clouded weather [look here for ingredients to craft one.](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Foglet+Decoction) But that's not a constant boost to your sign intensity, but it does prove to be a significant plus.

If you're looking to get maximum sign intensity with no conditions, abilities, or temporary effects, your build is excellent.